# How to use CryptoJS in power Automate Desktop?

Tags: javascript, power-automate-desktop

Dears I am getting this error when trying to use CryptoJS for string , I have used Run JavaScript on Microsoft Power Automat Desktop :

> 2\Robin\us1w21ocz5s.tmp(13, 1) Microsoft JScript runtime error:
> 'CryptoJS' is undefined

```
// Create a new Date object to represent the current UTC date
var currentDate = new Date();
// Get UTC year, month, and date components
var year = currentDate.getUTCFullYear().toString();
var month = (currentDate.getUTCMonth()+1).toString(); 
// Months are zero-indexed, so add 1
var day = currentDate.getUTCDate().toString();
// Combine components to create the formatted UTC date
var formattedUTCDate = year + month + day;
var pass = "MNA8016fa5558"+ formattedUTCDate +"0957b65ffr534w2f19f1";
var enc_pass = CryptoJS.SHA1(pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
WScript.Echo(enc_pass);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS is an external javascript 'library' and is not part of PAD by default.

You first have to make sure CryptoJS exist in your script. The error you are getting indicates that CryptoJS does not exist.

You can download the sha1.js code from [CryptoJS Github](https://github.com/crypto-js/crypto-js/blob/latest/dist/sha1.js) or whatever encryption algorithm you wish to use.

Then load the file as part of your flow actions, read the CryptoJS file into text so that you can add it to your script.

Copy and paste this into PAD:

```
   SET CriptoJS_External_Path TO $'''C:\\Temp\\pad\\sha1.js'''

   File.ReadTextFromFile.ReadText File: CriptoJS_External_Path Encoding: 
   File.TextFileEncoding.UTF8 Content=> CriptoJSCode

   @@copilotGeneratedAction: 'False'
   Scripting.RunJavascript.RunJavascript JavascriptCode: $'''%CriptoJSCode%

   // your code here.....
   var pass = \"MNA8016fa5558\"+ formattedUTCDate +\"0957b65ffr534w2f19f1\";

   var enc_pass = CryptoJS.SHA1(pass).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

   WScript.Echo(enc_pass);''' ScriptOutput=> JavascriptOutput
```

It should look something like this:
as you can see the CryptoJS code is imported via a variable.. you could have copied and pasted the content of the sha1,js file here as well.

[image: jscode action]

and

[image: flow actions]

and your variable value

[image: variable produced]